# how to create a logical test if a certain element is not in a vector that will yield a TRUE

Tags: r

I'm writing a for loop and I need a line of code that will return TRUE when a certain element is included in a sample vector and another certain element is not included in the sample vector.

The "else if" statement below is where I need help. I need it to be if any element in the sample equals 10 and no element in the sample equals 9. Obviously the any(!=9) doesn't work.

```
Questions<-1:10
numSamples<-1000000
score<-rep(NA,times=numSamples)
for(i in 1:numSamples){

 }else if(any(Firstsample==10) & any(Firstsample!=9)){
     score<-1
 }else{
     score<-0
}}
sum(score)/numSamples
```

Comment: Maybe you need `all(Firstsample != 9)`?

Comment: I'd use `%in%.` As in, `else if(10 %in% Firstsample & ! 9 %in% Firstsample)`